# Como carregar vários conteúdos em flash sem entrar em conflito com a maintimeline de outro conteúdo carregado anteriormente usando o Loader.loadBytes?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe-air

No meu projeto, estou tentando salvar todos os swfs carregados na memória para deixar os usuários livres de delay... **Eu não posso** e não quero usar "*Loader.unloadAndStop()*" no Loader.

Estou salvando todos os os conteúdos carregados dentro de um Object.

Por Exemplo:

```
var CacheSWF:Object = new Object();
var CurrentSWF:String;

function GetSWF(swf:String):void {
    this.CurrentSWF = swf;

    if (this.CacheSWF[this.CurrentSWF] != null) {
        this.removeAllChildren();
        stage.addChild(this.CacheSWF[this.CurrentSWF]);
    } else {
        var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        ldr.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
        ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.loadBytesSWF);
        ldr.load(new URLRequest(this.CurrentSWF));
    }
}

function loadBytesSWF(evt:Event):void {
    var ldr:Loader = new Loader();
    ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, this.saveSWF);
    ldr.loadBytes(ByteArray((evt.target as URLLoader).data));
}

function saveSWF(evt:Event):void {
    this.removeAllChildren();
    this.CacheSWF[this.CurrentSWF] = MovieClip(Loader(evt.target.loader).content);
    stage.addChild(this.CacheSWF[this.CurrentSWF]);
}

function removeAllChildren():void {
    while (stage.numChildren > 0) {
        stage.removeChildAt(0);
    }
}
```

Mas eu estou tendo algum tipo de conflito quando tento carregar outro swf. O segundo MovieClip carregado executa a maintimeline do primeiro MovieClip carregado. Não tenho ideia de como consertar isso.

Exemplo:

```
this.GetSWF("file1.swf"); //Eu tenho o MovieClip e MainTimeLine corretos

//Faço algo...

this.GetSWF("file2.swf"); //Eu tenho o MovieClip correto mas o conteúdo executa a função MainTimeLine do "file1.swf"
```

Se não há como salvar do modo que eu quero, como posso limpá-lo (o Loader) sem usar "*Loader.unloadAndStop()*" ou "*Loader.unload()*"?

> 1. Baseado na biblioteca da Adobe, o *Loader.unload()* não funciona para o conteúdo carregado por *Loader.loadBytes()*;
> 2. Não posso usar *Loader.unloadAndStop()* porque essa função não existe para Flash 9 (o destino do meu projeto).

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/408292/edit) e traduza a pergunta.

Comment: Carlos, já tive muito problema com relação e há um tempo desisti de tentar dar "unload" nos swfs carregados pelo loadBytes. O meu palpite é que assim que você carrega um SWF externo, as bibliotecas e códigos fontes que você usa, inclusive as imagens e vídeos, são mesclados com o SWF que está carregando. Se você der o Loader.unload(), apenas o código contido na estrutura principal dele é que será descarregado, o restante permanecerá.

Comment: Por outro lado, o Loader.unload() funciona muito bem quando carregado com Loader.load(). Essa particularidade restringe um pouco os recursos que você pode utilizar no SWF externo, mas é exatamente essa bolha que é descarregada quando você chama Loader.unload(). Para tentar contornar isso, você pode dar uma olhada no objeto [ApplicationDomain](https://help.adobe.com/pt_BR/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html).

Comment: O problema é que não tenho alternativa. O destino de minha aplicação é AIR Android.
Usando apenas o Loader.load() eu não consigo carregar swfs externos, apenas do modo como exemplifiquei acima. Senão eu recebo um erro de violação de segurança, mesmo usando LoaderContext.

`var appDomain = new ApplicationDomain();
var appContext = new LoaderContext(true, appDomain);
appContext.applicationDomain = ApplicationDomain.currentDomain;
appContext.checkPolicyFile = false;
appContext.allowCodeImport = true;
appContext.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true;`